# Problem making a matrix with a vertical line in it (Latex)

Tags: matrices

I am trying to make a matrix in Latex with a vertical line in the middle of it, but I am missing a litte point. Can't figure out what I am missing:( Here is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
    A_{eq} = 
    \left[\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
        \begin{matrix}
            I & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 \\
            -A & I & \ddots &  & \vdots \\
            0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            \vdots & \ddots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots \\
            0 & \dots & 0 & -A & I \\
        \end{matrix}
            & -B & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 \\
            & 0 & \ddots & \ddots &  & \vdots \\
            & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            & \vdots &  & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
            & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 & -B \\
    \end{array} \right]
  \end{equation}
```

This is what I get out of this code.
[image: matrix]
I don't understand why there are spaces here. Anyone who can help?

Comment: Please complete the example to a complete MWE (program that we can directly test) and do yo want to have the "B" part diagonally  below the first matrix or next to next to it. Th espacing is due to the fact that you have in total 5 rows where the first row contains the first matrix followed by the columns starting with "-B".

Comment: Are you looking for something that resembles [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUrnX.png)?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, but I found the problem thanks some help down here. You are very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot a second `matrix`-environment, didn't you?

Latex sees the matrix as an element of the first line of your array, that's why the matrix is aligned with the rest of the first array line and all the rest is below. In this solution the array consists of only two elements, the first and the second matrix. The `@{}`s (or `{\,}`, as egreg suggests in a comment) in the second argument of `\begin{array}` eliminate (adapt) the additional spaces.

In case that the subscript `eq` is non-numeric, I'd recommend to use `A_{\mathrm{eq}}` to make it upright.

```
\begin{equation}
      A_{eq} = 
      \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}}
         \begin{matrix}
            I      & 0      & \dots  & \dots  & 0      \\
            -A     & I      & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
            0      & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            \vdots & \ddots & 0      & \ddots & \vdots \\
            0      & \dots  & 0      & -A     & I
         \end{matrix}
         &
         \begin{matrix}
            -B     & 0      & \dots  & \dots  & 0      \\
            0      & \ddots & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
            \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            \vdots &        & \ddots & \ddots & 0      \\
            0      & \dots  & \dots  & 0      & -B
         \end{matrix}
      \end{array} \right]
   \end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh of course! Thank you so much, it worked now!

Comment: @user239345 I am just guessing, but I think in the penultimate line there should be `-A` (or `\ddots`) instead of `0`. And please use the updated version of this code as there was still a mistake made by me.

Comment: I'd probably not suppress completely the space around the vertical bar; try with `@{\,}|\@{\,}` and I believe you'd get something better.

Comment: Good observation! Clearly I need to double check my work! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For information, here is what you can obtain for this matrix with `nicematrix`.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{nicematrix}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
 A_{\text{eq}} =
 \begin{bNiceArray}{*{5}{c}|*{5}{c}}[nullify-dots,columns-width=auto]
 I      & 0      & \Cdots &    & 0      & -B     & 0      & \Cdots &   & 0 \\
 -A     & I      & \Ddots &    & \Vdots & 0      & \Ddots & \Ddots &   & \Vdots \\
 0      & \Ddots & \Ddots &    &        & \Vdots & \Ddots &        &   &        \\
 \Vdots & \Ddots &        &    & 0      &        &        &        &   & 0 \\
  0     & \Cdots & 0      & -A & I      & 0      & \Cdots &        & 0 & -B
 \end{bNiceArray}
 \end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to do that with  a single `blockarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    A_{eq} =
   \begin{blockarray}{[*{5}{c}|*{5}{c}]}
            I & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & -B & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \bigstrut[t]\\
            -A & I & \ddots & & \vdots & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
            0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            \vdots & \ddots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
             0 & \dots & 0 & -A & I & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & -B \bigstrut[b]
  \end{blockarray}
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]